# TS2345: type 'Construct' is not a class derived from 'Construct'

Tags: typescript

Following the tutorial on this page: https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/40-hit-counter/300-resources.html

I believe `this`, passed to the `Table` constructor, should be `HitCounter`, a sub-constructor of `cdk.Construct`

It returns this lint:

```
this: this
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
  Type 'HitCounter' is not assignable to type 'Construct'.
    Property 'onValidate' is protected but type 'Construct' is not a class derived from 'Construct'.ts(2345)
```

I also get an internal server error on this step. Anyone know what the issue is?

```
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda";
import * as dynamodb from "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb";

export interface HitCounterProps { downstream : lambda.IFunction; }

export class HitCounter extends cdk.Construct {
   public readonly handler: lambda.Function;

   constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: HitCounterProps) {
      super(scope, id);

      const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "Hits", { // lints `this`
         partitionKey : { 
            name : "path", 
            type : dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING 
         }
      });
      <more code removed>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue. You have to set all the different cdk packages to the same version, see https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/542#issuecomment-449694450.

Comment: `you might not only want to nuke your node_modules folder, but as well the package-lock.json`

Answer (score 6):

1. cd to your project path
2. run: `npx npm-check-updates -u`
3. run: `npm install`
4. restart your IDE